# Index of subgroup of $\mathbb Z^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Let $\Lambda$ be a full-rank subgroup of $\mathbb Z^n$ generated by $v_1,...,v_n$. Is there a good way to prove that the index $[\mathbb Z^n:\Lambda]$ is equal to the absolute value of $\det [v_1,...,v_n]$?

The only argument I came up with is that since fundamental parallelotopes tile the space, in a very large volume $V$ there would be approximately $V$ lattice points and $V/\det[v_1,...,v_n]$ fundamental parallelotope, thus every parallelotope must contain exactly $\det[v_1,...,v_n]$ lattice points. However, this seems very messy to make rigorous.

Comment: @AnneBauval although they do give a proof for this question in the link you provided, its not the main concern of the question in the link, and the answer assumes the questioner has already observed the fact themselves, meaning they probably already had the intuition for why it is the case

Comment: Anyway, they do prove it indeed, so it definitely answers the OP's question.